# Failed to mount external hardisk volume

Tags: mount, kali-linux, hard-disk

I need to transfer data from my old kali-linux machine to the current one. I copued directory to hard drive without issue, then connected it to my current pc, I get this error:

[image]

My external hard disk has 3 volumes and the other 2 work, so only the one that copied the directory is causing the issue. The only solution that I know is running disk check in windows. My pc has dual boots, windows and kali-linux and I am tired of booting to windows and then boot to kali machine again.

I want to know what is causing the issue and how can I solve it on linux without booting to windows.

I connect the hard disk to the pc that allowed copying the directory and I am getting the same error. If it would cause an error, why did it allow copying in the first place?

Answer (score -1):

[Dalek_01]
you can't use hhd with NTFS (WINDOWS) in kali go into your driver media where you mount disks
try THIS

format your partition as ext4 (for Kali)
if this did  not work TRY

1 : check filesystem

2 : repair filesystem

mount your disk

should be working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).